# Recommendations for Stand-Alone NoSQL Database C++ Library

Tags: library, database, c++, json, nosql

I am developing a Linux-only C++ open-source tool for (civilian) aircraft surveillance data inspection - think Radar data display and analysis ([link](https://github.com/hpuhr/COMPASS)).

Currently the app works with SQLite3, but I am considering the switch to a NoSQL database, to be able to support less structured data and a small-scale OR mapping.

The database content will, for the most part, be lots of JSON (see [example](https://github.com/hpuhr/jASTERIX#decode--print)) objects, e.g. 50+ million will not be unusual. I would prefer for it to be a standalone database (1 file container), just for ease of usage. Only one application will use the database, and single-threaded access would be ok (although multiple parallel read operations would be nice to have).

Performance and stability would be top priority, ease of usage and efficient storage second. In-memory (RAM) storage as an option would be a plus.

Common operations:

- Write once, read often (import data once, then read operations during display/inspection)
- Bulk reads (often, almost all of the data will be read)
- Normal search operations (filtering on a few attribute conditions, nothing complicated)
- Quick look-up of single entries (e.g. using a UUID or similar)

I will do a quick prototype of each library of interest to test performance and ease of usage.

So finally my question: What C++ libraries would you recommend I have a look at?

Current candidates:

- [UnQLite](https://unqlite.org/)